# Is it possible to use new line break in a language files?

Tags: laravel, escaping, laravel-5, html-entities

I've tried to use `<br />`, `\n\r`, `&#13;&#10;` to start new line but all these symbols do not work, because Laravel escapes messages.

I wonder is there any way to start new line in a message?

```
// resources/lang/en

return [
    'some_message' => 'Some text &#13;&#10; New line here'
];
```

I understand I could extend `Translator` class or write my own helper, but I'm looking for more elegant solution.

Comment: How do you output this message?  With `{{ }}` or with `{!! !!}`?

Comment: I'm using `trans()` in a service provider to `flash()` a message to a session.

Comment: At a glance on `Translator.php` I can't find any place where message could be escaped. `trans` function returns already escaped message?

Comment: Check where you actually output it, to see if you can change it to non-escaping there.

Comment: @JoelHinz, I've stuck with my service provider, so I totally forgot I'm actually printing it in a view, silly me. Thanks for help. You can write an answer, so I could accept and upvote it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check where you actually output it, to see if you can change it to non-escaping there.